# Cleaning a pandas dataframe formed from 3500 different text documents - scraped articles

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I have 3500+ scraped text files, which are scraped from same or different sources, the text files are such that they are articles and they also contain ads in scraped text, I want to remove these from starting and last, where they are as the content i\lies in between only.

I loaded all the  text files and converted them into a pandas data frame.

```
import io
loc = 'D://Users/Desktop/tdm_input'
os.chdir(loc)
filelist = os.listdir(loc)
data = []
path = loc
files = [f for f in os.listdir(path) if os.path.isfile(f)]
for f in files:
    with io.open(f,'r', encoding='ISO-8859-1') as myfile:
        data.append(myfile.read())

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print (df.shape)

df.columns = ['text']
df.head()


text
0   What Fresh Hell Is This? January 31, 2018 ...A...
1   What Fresh Hell Is This? February 27, 2018 My ...
2   What Fresh Hell Is This? March 31, 2018 Trump ...
3   What Fresh Hell Is This? April 29, 2018 Michel...
4   Join Email List Contribute Join AMERICAblog Ac...
5   Join Email List Contribute Join AMERICAblog Ac...
6   Join Email List Contribute Join AMERICAblog Ac...
7   Join Email List Contribute Join AMERICAblog Ac...
8   Skip to content Facebook ASF On Twitter ASF On...
9   Skip to content Facebook ASF On Twitter ASF On...
10  Skip to content Facebook ASF On Twitter ASF On...
11  Skip to content Facebook ASF On Twitter ASF On...
12  Skip to content Facebook ASF On Twitter ASF On...
13  Skip to content Facebook ASF On Twitter ASF On...
14  Skip to content Facebook ASF On Twitter ASF On...
15  Skip to content Facebook ASF On Twitter ASF On...
16  Skip to content Facebook ASF On Twitter ASF On...
17  Skip to content Facebook ASF On Twitter ASF On...
18  Skip to content Facebook ASF On Twitter ASF On...
19  Skip to content Facebook ASF On Twitter ASF On...
20  Skip to content Facebook ASF On Twitter ASF On...
21  Skip to content Facebook ASF On Twitter ASF On...
22  Skip to content Facebook ASF On Twitter ASF On...
23  Skip to content Facebook ASF On Twitter ASF On...
24  Skip to content Facebook ASF On Twitter ASF On...
25  Skip to content Facebook ASF On Twitter ASF On...
26  Skip to content Facebook ASF On Twitter ASF On...
27  Skip to content Facebook ASF On Twitter ASF On...
28  Skip to content Facebook ASF On Twitter ASF On...
29  Skip to content Facebook ASF On Twitter ASF On...
30  Skip to content Facebook ASF On Twitter ASF On...
31  Skip to content Facebook ASF On Twitter ASF On...
32  Skip to content Facebook ASF On Twitter ASF On...
33  Skip to content Facebook ASF On Twitter ASF On...
34  Skip to content Facebook ASF On Twitter ASF On...
35  Skip to content Facebook ASF On Twitter ASF On...
36  Skip to content Facebook ASF On Twitter ASF On...
37  Skip to content Facebook ASF On Twitter ASF On...
38  Skip to content Facebook ASF On Twitter ASF On...
39  Skip to content Facebook ASF On Twitter ASF On...
40  Skip to content Facebook ASF On Twitter ASF On...
41  Skip to content Facebook ASF On Twitter ASF On...
42  Skip to content Facebook ASF On Twitter ASF On...
43  Skip to content Facebook ASF On Twitter ASF On...
44  French Politics An American observer comments ...
45  French Politics An American observer comments ...
46  DOW JONES, A NEWS CORP COMPANY News Corp is a ...
47  DOW JONES, A NEWS CORP COMPANY News Corp is a ...
48  DOW JONES, A NEWS CORP COMPANY News Corp is a ...
49  DOW JONES, A NEWS CORP COMPANY News Corp is a ...
```

My data frame, looks like, how can I clean it.
Here is the link to my dataframe.

I also extracted these sentences which I wish to remove in the beginning and end, in a text file, how can i use it to clean y pandas dataframe.

here is the link;
Data = https://drive.google.com/open?id=1HJbWTUMfiBV54EEtgSXTcsQLzQT1rFgz
flitered_text = https://drive.google.com/open?id=1GApPKvA82tx4CDtlOTqe99zKXS3AHiuD